# LVM2 Partitions are not mounted after reboot

Tags: mount, lvm, automount

i have a ubuntu server system on a dell hardware with two logical LVM2 volumes. One is the boot system an the other is the data storage exist out of two physicall drives which are organized as a RAID1. After boot the data storage is not automatically mounted.

```
root@pluto:/# pvs
  PV         VG        Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree  
  /dev/sda3  ubuntu-vg lvm2 a--  445.62g 178.78g
  /dev/sdb1  data-vg   lvm2 a--   <7.28t  <2.19t
```

lvscan delivers all the volume groups

```
root@pluto:/# lvscan 
  ACTIVE   Original '/dev/data-vg/data-lv' [4.00 TiB] inherit
  ACTIVE   Snapshot '/dev/data-vg/data-snapshot' [1.09 TiB] inherit
  ACTIVE   Original '/dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv' [200.00 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE   Snapshot '/dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-snapshot' [<66.84 GiB] inherit
```

lvdisplay shows also all the volume groups.

```
root@pluto:/# lvdisplay 
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/data-vg/data-lv
  LV Name                data-lv
  VG Name                data-vg
  LV UUID                AC5nN1-aGdj-lgfo-PqBP-lIkZ-D5vx-tcO6IP
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time pluto, 2020-11-10 14:19:31 +0100
  LV snapshot status     source of
                         data-snapshot [active]
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                4.00 TiB
  Current LE             1048576
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:5
   
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/data-vg/data-snapshot
  LV Name                data-snapshot
  VG Name                data-vg
  LV UUID                oHsjAj-79tp-UMN3-MUb6-Efwc-Zl43-XHEGx1
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time pluto, 2020-11-10 14:19:45 +0100
  LV snapshot status     active destination for data-lv
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                4.00 TiB
  Current LE             1048576
  COW-table size         1.09 TiB
  COW-table LE           286137
  Allocated to snapshot  100.00%
  Snapshot chunk size    4.00 KiB
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:7
   
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv
  LV Name                ubuntu-lv
  VG Name                ubuntu-vg
  LV UUID                eiVtC7-Uz40-BQdS-Dsrj-vgUw-gL6v-BwLfqt
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time ubuntu-server, 2020-11-10 16:07:23 +0100
  LV snapshot status     source of
                         ubuntu-snapshot [active]
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                200.00 GiB
  Current LE             51200
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:1
   
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-snapshot
  LV Name                ubuntu-snapshot
  VG Name                ubuntu-vg
  LV UUID                CL35iM-uBSY-QC5A-FvLD-UHiF-M7Cw-rH831B
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time pluto, 2020-11-10 16:26:42 +0100
  LV snapshot status     active destination for ubuntu-lv
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                200.00 GiB
  Current LE             51200
  COW-table size         <66.84 GiB
  COW-table LE           17111
  Allocated to snapshot  10.33%
  Snapshot chunk size    4.00 KiB
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:3
```

```
root@pluto:/# lsblk
NAME                                MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0                                 7:0    0  97.8M  1 loop /snap/core/10185
loop1                                 7:1    0    55M  1 loop /snap/core18/1880
loop2                                 7:2    0  29.9M  1 loop /snap/snapd/8542
loop3                                 7:3    0  55.4M  1 loop /snap/core18/1932
loop4                                 7:4    0  67.8M  1 loop /snap/lxd/18150
loop5                                 7:5    0  71.3M  1 loop /snap/lxd/16099
loop6                                 7:6    0    31M  1 loop /snap/snapd/9721
sda                                   8:0    0 446.6G  0 disk 
├─sda1                                8:1    0     1M  0 part 
├─sda2                                8:2    0     1G  0 part /boot
└─sda3                                8:3    0 445.6G  0 part 
  ├─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv-real      253:0    0   200G  0 lvm  
  │ ├─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv         253:1    0   200G  0 lvm  /
  │ └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--snapshot   253:3    0   200G  0 lvm  
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--snapshot-cow 253:2    0  66.9G  0 lvm  
    └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--snapshot   253:3    0   200G  0 lvm  
sdb                                   8:16   0   7.3T  0 disk 
└─sdb1                                8:17   0   7.3T  0 part 
  └─data--vg-data--snapshot-cow     253:6    0   1.1T  0 lvm  
sr0                                  11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

When I call vgscan --mknodes the device in /dev/data-vg are generated. And the message is raised.

```
root@pluto:/# vgscan --mknodes
  Found volume group "data-vg" using metadata type lvm2
  Found volume group "ubuntu-vg" using metadata type lvm2
  The link /dev/data-vg/data-lv should have been created by udev but it was not found. Falling back to direct link creation.
  The link /dev/data-vg/data-snapshot should have been created by udev but it was not found. Falling back to direct link creation.
```

When I call vgchange -a y you can see in the journal pluto lvm[972]: Target (null) is not snapshot.

After a long time the command end and the lvm are available.

```
  device-mapper: reload ioctl on  (253:7) failed: Invalid argument
  2 logical volume(s) in volume group "data-vg" now active
  2 logical volume(s) in volume group "ubuntu-vg" now active
```

```
root@pluto:/dev# lsblk 
NAME                                MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0                                 7:0    0  97.8M  1 loop /snap/core/10185
loop1                                 7:1    0    55M  1 loop /snap/core18/1880
loop2                                 7:2    0  29.9M  1 loop /snap/snapd/8542
loop3                                 7:3    0  55.4M  1 loop /snap/core18/1932
loop4                                 7:4    0  67.8M  1 loop /snap/lxd/18150
loop5                                 7:5    0  71.3M  1 loop /snap/lxd/16099
loop6                                 7:6    0    31M  1 loop /snap/snapd/9721
sda                                   8:0    0 446.6G  0 disk 
├─sda1                                8:1    0     1M  0 part 
├─sda2                                8:2    0     1G  0 part /boot
└─sda3                                8:3    0 445.6G  0 part 
  ├─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv-real      253:0    0   200G  0 lvm  
  │ ├─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv         253:1    0   200G  0 lvm  /
  │ └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--snapshot   253:3    0   200G  0 lvm  
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--snapshot-cow 253:2    0  66.9G  0 lvm  
    └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--snapshot   253:3    0   200G  0 lvm  
sdb                                   8:16   0   7.3T  0 disk 
└─sdb1                                8:17   0   7.3T  0 part 
  ├─data--vg-data--lv-real          253:4    0     4T  0 lvm  
  │ ├─data--vg-data--lv             253:5    0     4T  0 lvm  
  │ └─data--vg-data--snapshot       253:7    0     4T  0 lvm  
  └─data--vg-data--snapshot-cow     253:6    0   1.1T  0 lvm  
    └─data--vg-data--snapshot       253:7    0     4T  0 lvm  
sr0
```

And the i am able to mount the logical volume.

My aim is to get the volumes directly mounted during boot. Please can you help me.

best regards

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. Dell hardware, 2x SSD in RAID1 with LVM for boot (works perfectly), 2x SSD in RAID1 with LVM for data. The data LV doesn't activate on boot *most of the time*. Rarely, it will activate on boot.

Entering the OS and running `vgchange -ay` will activate the LV and it works correctly. It seems to be a race condition that has existed for at least 11 years: https://serverfault.com/questions/199185/logical-volumes-are-inactive-at-boot-time

I have tried many solutions so far and none have worked.